# Output sum of element entered by user to an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

i am currently working on a java code that takes input from user and outputs the size of arraylist, the sum of numbers entered, the average and the maximum number entered. i have not been able to complete the sum as the for loop is not calculating result. I would appreciate any suggestions. my code is as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        double size = 0;
        double a = -999;
        double total = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for user input

        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();
        System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            //assign the nextDouble to a variable
            double tmp = in.nextDouble();
            //test the variable
            if (tmp != a) {
                //add the variable
                //if you want to add -999 to the inputs then this next line above the test.
                inputs.add(tmp);
                System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
            } else {
                inputs.size(); // get size of input
                System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + inputs.size());
                break;
            }
        }
        for (double sum : inputs) {
            total += sum;
            System.out.println("The sum of numbers entered is " + total);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` in the `for` loop causes the loop to exit. Here, it's causing the loop to exit on the first iteration, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Move the `println` outside the loop, and remove the `break`:

```
for (double sum : inputs) {
    total += sum;
}

System.out.println("The sum of numbers entered is " + total);
```

This allows the `for` loop to iterate the entire list while calculating the sum so you can print it after instead of exiting prematurely.

---

Also note that this:

```
inputs.size(); // get size of input
```

Isn't doing anything useful. `size` returns the size of `inputs`, then you don't do anything with that number, so it's lost. You should just remove that line since you call `size` again on the next line anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have in your code is you have a break condition in your for loop

The correct code is the following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    double size = 0;
    double a = -999;
    double total = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for user input

    ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        //assign the nextDouble to a variable
        double tmp = in.nextDouble();
        //test the variable
        if (tmp != a) {
            //add the variable
            //if you want to add -999 to the inputs then this next line above the test.
            inputs.add(tmp);
            System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
        } else {
            inputs.size(); // get size of input
            System.out.println("Numbers entered: " + inputs.size());
            break;
        }
    }
    for (double sum : inputs) {
        total += sum;
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of numbers entered is " + total);

}
}
```

Comment: hi would you have any advise of how to find the largest number entered by user?#

Comment: Only store it in a local variable in the while block